# Accessing global object from content script in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have defined a global object in a .js file. For example file1.js contains the global object SomeObject. This file gets loaded in background.html.

Since file1.js is included in background.html, I am able to access the global object in this page. So no issues here.

When an event like click on the extension button is performed, I am running a content script using the `chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "contentscript.js"});` api.

How can I access SomeObject in the contentscript in this case?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is **no way to get direct access** to the background page's global object from a [Content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) or **injected script**.

To use a background page's method from an injected script , follow these steps:

1. **Content Script**: Bind an event listener to the page <sup>[example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9636008/938089?chrome-extension-retrieving-gmails-original-message)</sup>.

   *Whenever you want to notify the method from the background page:*
2. **Injected script**: Create and fire this specific event <sup>[example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9636008/938089?chrome-extension-retrieving-gmails-original-message)</sup>.

   → The event listener from **1)** gets triggered.
3. In this event listener, use [`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-sendMessage) to request the functionality from the background <sup>[example 2](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#simple)</sup>.
4. In the background page, handle this request using [`chrome.runtime.onMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onMessage).
5. Optionally, inject code in the original tab using [`chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, func)`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript).

To use a background page's method from a Content script, only steps 3 and 4 are needed.
Here's an example, in which the content script communicates with the background page:

```
// Example background page
function some_method(arg_name) {
    return localStorage.getItem(arg_name);
}
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, callback) {
    if (request.type == 'localStorage - step 4') {
        callback( some_method(request.name) );
    } else if (request.type == 'localStorage - step 5') {
        localStorage.setItem(request.name, request.value);
    }
});

// Example contentscript.js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    type: 'localStorage - step 4',
    name: 'preference'
}, function(value) {
    if (value === null) {
        // Example: If no preference is set, set one:
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            type: 'localStorage - step 5',
            name: 'preference',
            value: 'default'
        });
    }
});
```

### See also

- SO: What you **should** know about [background scripts vs Content Scripts vs Injected scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9916089/938089?chrome-extension-auto-run-a-function).
- SO: Example code: [Communicating between an Injected script and a Content script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9636008/938089?chrome-extension-retrieving-gmails-original-message).

Comment: is there any way to do it without modifying the content script in any way?

Comment: bug. Notice that your sendMessage does not have the same number of arguments as the addListener.

Comment: after getting my code to work, I got: chrome.runtime.sendMessage(chrome.runtime.id, arg, sender_id, cb);