# How could i achieve to access the data which where set on options page in the content script eg. in the google chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I am setting some values at the option page. This is now working okay. But i am unable to access the data setted in the background.html or in the content script. I have read that something like this is possible with messaging but for me is the documentation a little bit hard to understand. If someone could point me out in the right direction it would be good.
Example story>
I am setting this value at the options page `localStorage.setItem("somedata" , "true");`
Then if i would access the same data on the page where the extension would be to run i get it like this:

```
localStorage.getItem("somedata");
```

And the value is `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content scripts cannot directly read the localStorage values from the background page. If you wish to read localStorage key-value pairs, see this answer which provides an explanation plus code for achieving this: [Accessing global object from content script in chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052259/accessing-global-object-from-content-script-in-chrome-extension/10053750#10053750)

Although the previous method works, I recommend the [`chrome.storage`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) API instead: This can be used by all extension pages. A huge difference between `localStorage` and `chrome.storage` is that `chrome.storage` is an **asynchronous** API.

Here's an example to illustrate the dfferences:

```
// synchronous localStorage
localStorage.setItem('keyname', 'value');
alert(localStorage.getItem('keyname'));

// asynchronous chrome.storage
chrome.storage.local.set({keyname: 'value'}, function() {
    chrome.storage.local.get('keyname', function(items) {
        alert(items.keyname);
    });
});
```

On the first sight, the `chrome.storage` API looks more convoluted. However, if you want to save data within an extension, it's the best way to do so. The `localStorage` approach takes much more code (see the answer I linked on top of this answer) to achieve the same functionality. And, it's *also* asynchronous.